# How the user authorization is done using Firebase in a webapp?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I've got following code for user authorization using Firebase but I'm not able to understand the code. Below the code I've mentioned the doubts I'm facing. Plase someone clarify them.

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://prj_name.firebaseio.com");
var loggedInUser = [];
$(document).ready(function() {
    authData=ref.getAuth();

    if(authData == null){
        //TODO find an elegant way to manage authorization 
    //  window.location = "../index.html";
    }else{
        ref.child("users").child(authData.uid).on("value", function(snapshot){
            $( "span.user-name").html(snapshot.val().displayName);  
            loggedInUser.displayName = snapshot.val().displayName;
        });

    }

    $("#cPassword").focusout(function() {
        validatePassword($("#cPassword"), $("#password"));
    });


    $(document).on("click", ".clickable-row" ,function(){
        window.document.location = $(this).data("href");
    });
});

function validatePassword(password, cPassword) {
    if (cPassword.val() != password.val()) {
        cPassword.css('border-color', 'red');
        password.css('border-color', 'red');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

All the necessary libraries like firebase have been included and above code is working absolutely fine, the only concern is I'm not able to understand it.

My doubts are as follows :

1. What does the line `authData=ref.getAuth();` do and what authData contains after it get execute?
2. In else block, what is **value** and **snapshot**. I  didn't understand at all the line. `ref.child("users").child(authData.uid).on("value", function(snapshot)`

Can someone please clarify my doubts? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok here goes:

Firstly you should update your firebase security rules first if you haven't already: [Firebase security rules guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/)

1. ref.getAuth() returns a value that will either be null if you haven't been authorised yet or it will contain an object with some info about how the user was authorised (custom token, facebook id, email etc.)
2. This line: `ref.child("users").child(authData.uid).on("value", function(snapshot)`. Here  you're basically requesting some data from your users collection: '/users/{some unique id}'. When you request the data from firebase, as soon as the data is ready to be used, Firebase triggers the "value" callback and passes the data (snapshot) using this callback.

The firebase docs are very good, I would advise reading through the entire web guide. [Firebase web guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/)

I hope I've been able to clear some things up for you!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But still one doubt remaining what is the role of 'value' in function? Please elaborate.

Comment: When you request the data from firebase, as soon as the data is ready to be used, Firebase triggers the "value" callback and passes the data (snapshot) using this callback.